# Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

My goal is to add a string to array, and I do that in a method which I call.

In this method, I get a null value in the array, and don't know why. I have this at the start of my class:

```
NSMutableArray *listOfEvents;
```

and a method which I call on each event:

```
-(void)EventList
{
    [listOfEvents addObject:@"ran"];
    NSLog(@"%@", listOfEvents);     
}
```

I get `(null)` in the log.

If I put the array definition  `NSMutableArray *listOfEvents;` in the function body, I get the string value `@"ran"`, each time, so the array always has only one value, instead of having many strings named `@"ran"`.

What's wrong with this? It seems that I can't understand something about arrays, even though I have read the documents a number of times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/) or [Having Problems with Adding Objects to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716876/) or [NSMutableArray addObject not affecting count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683761/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you haven't initialized `listOfEvents`.

Make sure you do `listOfEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in your class's `init` method. Also make sure you release it in your class's `dealloc` method.

Comment: ok i did listOfEvents=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in the function body so then i only get the value ran, but only one value. it wouldnt add this string every time again and again.. why ?

Comment: If you're running EventList multiple times per instance of your class then it will keep adding the string to the array. If you're running EventList with a new instance of your class each time, then the array is obviously a new array each time as well.

Comment: thanks. i couldnt understand you, each time i press a button(i use cocos2d) i call this function. what do i have to change in order to add new values again and again ? it runs as instance of my class.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made a new question that included code for your entire class, as well as where you're calling it from.

Comment: `listOfEvents=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` is right, but **you need to move it to your class's `init` method** so it's only called once.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked but i dont know why. can you direct me to read about it more? there is probably something i dont understand about alloc. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting `nil` in your log message, you need to make sure listOfEvents is non-nil before adding your object. IE:

```
-(void)EventList
{
    if (listOfEvents == nil) {
        listOfEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [listOfEvents addObject:@"ran"];
    NSLog(@"%@",listOfEvents);      
}
```

In Objective-C, messages with `void` return types sent to `nil` go to [absolutely-silent nowhere-land.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html)

Also, for the sake of balance, be sure you have a `[listOfEvents release]` call in your `dealloc` implementation.

Comment: thanks a lot. i did that, but then i only see the value ran. even if i call it 10 times,only one string value appear-ran.

Comment: Two minor points: logging `nil` prints `(null)`, and _any_ message sent to `nil` does nothing, no matter the return type of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're not initializing your array.

```
NSMutableArray *listOfEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If that's your problem, I suggest reading the docs again. And not the NSMutableArray docs. Go back to *The Objective-C Programming Language* and others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `alloc` the `NSMutableArray`. Try doing this first -

`NSMutableArray *listOfEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

After this you could do what you what you planned...