# NSMutableArray : getObject method returning null

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This program should take 5 NSString's in input and print them.
I put them in an NSMutableArray.
During the loop if I try to print the NSString's they're printed correctly.
But when I try getting the objects from the array, I don't know why it returns null.
So if I try printing them in the second loop, they're all null.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* array;
    NSString* str=[[NSString alloc]init];
    char* cstr;
    cstr=(char*)calloc(100,sizeof(char));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        fgets(cstr,100,stdin);
        str=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstr];
        [array addObject : str];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        str=[array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
    }        
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is NSMutableArray showing count size of 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605251/why-is-nsmutablearray-showing-count-size-of-0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125326/cannot-add-items-to-an-nsmutablearray-ivar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
NSMutableArray* array;
```

You are declaring `array`, to be an `NSMutableArray`, but you're not setting the pointer to anything, so `array` is just `nil`.

You want to do this instead to allocate and initialize an actual instance of `NSMutableArray` and assign it to that pointer:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized your array.  You should put: `NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

or better yet: `NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];`