# Why is NSMutableArray showing count size of 0?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Very confused here...

I have a NSObject subclass called "Section" with a NSMutableArray property called "content"

```
 Section *sectionName = [[Section alloc] init];
 [[sectionName content] addObject:@"test"];
 [[sectionName content] addObject:@"test2"];
 [[sectionName content] addObject:@"test3"];

 NSLog(@"COUNT IS %i", [[sectionName content] count]);
```

Why is my NSLOG showing "COUNT IS 0"??

Comment: Can you post the property declaration of `content` and any code in `Section` that modifies it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you initializing `content` in your subclass? If not, that can be the problem!

Your init method should look like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
      _content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you're not using ARC your dealloc should look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  [_content release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Note if the OP is not using ARC this is a memory leak

Comment: Yeah, OP should definitely release `content` inside the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Nope that is still a memory leak if the OP is not using ARC. `alloc/init` is +1 retain and `content` is must likely declared `retain` which will be another +1, which you only release once in `dealloc`

Comment: @Paul.s Then correct my answer and don't behave like a schoolmaster ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you initializing array `content` inside `Section`? are you doing something like - `content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` ?

Lemme know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to allocate your `NSMutableArray` -- that is normally what causes this issue.

In your Section.m:

```
- (id) init {
    //...
    content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //...
}
```

Comment: That `init` method is not very safe