# Cannot add object to an NSMutableArray array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
@interface SimataDetailViewController () 

@property Simata *simata;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *simataList;

@end

@implementation SimataDetailViewController

@synthesize simataDataController=_simataDataController;
@synthesize category=_category;
@synthesize simata=_simata;
@synthesize simataList=_simataList;

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item



- (void) getSimataForCategory: (NSString *) inputCategory {

    unsigned count = [self.simataDataController.masterList2 count];


    while (count--) {

        if ([[[self.simataDataController objectSimataInListAtIndex:count] categoryCode] isEqual:inputCategory]){
            self.simata= [self.simataDataController objectSimataInListAtIndex:count];

            [self.simataList addObject:self.simata];                       
        }

    }

    NSLog(@"count, %u", [self.simataList count]);


}
```

Hello this is my first post, so please be patient.

I am trying to add object `self.simata` to array `self.simataList` but the array stays with zero objects. The object `self.simata` is not `nil` and I don't get any error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (+1 credit for making a fairly intelligible post as a newbie.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray addObject not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working) and [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125326/cannot-add-items-to-an-nsmutablearray-ivar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you have created an instance of the array before you use it?

```
self.simataList =[NSMutableArray array];
```

It could also be your self.simata being nil...

**EDIT**

You could create the array instance in the default init method:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        //do your object initialization here
        self.simataList =[NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: And where should I create the instance; I want array's scope to be all over the class.

Comment: creating an init method and placing it there is most likely the best solution in your case. See above...

Comment: It worked. I had to create an instance using the statement : *self.simataList =[NSMutableArray array];*.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad it worked. You can use break points in Xcode and hover over variables to check if they have been created. if you see a nil pointer (0x0) it generally means that you haven't initiated the object correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely self.simataList is nil.  Try NSLogging self.simataList itself, rather than its count.