# cant store objects at NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have code that scans and returns `NSString` like this:

```
NSString *GetText = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *ScannedText;
NSScanner *TheScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:somLongString];
int start=0;
int index=0;
int ObjectCount;
char c;
for (int i = 0; i < [somLongString length] ; i++) {
    c = [somLongString characterAtIndex:i];
    if (c == '=') {
        start = i+1;
        [TheScanner setScanLocation:start];
        [TheScanner scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:&GetText];
        NSLog( @"%@",GetText);
        [UserValuesObject insertObject:GetText  atIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"%@",[UserValuesObject objectAtIndex:index]);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Now I want to add the `GetText` object I am creating each time to an array.  When I try printing the first:

```
NSLog(@"%@",GetText);
```

it works! But when I am tring to add it to the object and then print (for debug) I am getting `null` on each print of the log:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[UserValuesObject objectAtIndex:index]);
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is `[UserValuesObject GetText atIndex:index];`?

Comment: Sorry on the code its like this [UserValuesObject insertObject:GetText atIndex:index];

Comment: Please include the code where you create `UserValuesObject` in the first place. Also, as a general note, variable names in objective-c start with a lower case letter and class names with an upper.

Comment: ok i have try to change it but still doesn't work

Comment: @orazran can you please show the code where you alloc/init  `UserValuesObject`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having problems with adding objects to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716876/having-problems-with-adding-objects-to-nsmutablearray) or [NSMutableArray addObject Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827058/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-working) or [Cannot add items to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125326/cannot-add-items-to-an-nsmutablearray-ivar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have initialized your array properly (or at all), try this (syntax improvements included):

```
NSString *getText = [NSString string];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:someLongString];
NSUInteger start = 0;
NSUInteger index = 0;
NSMutableArray *userValuesObject = [NSMutableArray array];
//  You should save the length of someLongString before starting the loop 
//   so that each iteration doesn't have to call length to see if i has 
//   reached length yet
for (int i = 0, len = [someLongString length]; i < len; ++i) {
    if ([somLongString characterAtIndex:i] == '=') {
        [scanner setScanLocation:(i + 1)];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:getText];
        NSLog(@"%@", GetText);
        [userValuesObject insertObject:getText atIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"%@", [userValuesObject objectAtIndex:index]);
        ++index;
    }
}
```

From [NSMutableArray Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/NSMutableArray_Class.pdf#page11):

> ```
> insertObject:atIndex:
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> `anObject` - The object to add to the array's content. This value must
>   not be nil.
>
> **Important: RaisesanNSInvalidArgumentException if anObject is nil.**
>
> `index` - The index in the array at which to insert anObject. This
>   value must not be greater than the count of elements in the array.
>
> **Important: Raises an NSRangeException if index is greater than the number of elements in the array.**
>
> If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are
>   shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room. Note that NSArray
>   objects are not like C arrays. That is, even though you specify a size
>   when you create an array, the specified size is regarded as a “hint”;
>   the actual size of the array is still 0. This means that you cannot
>   insert an object at an index greater than the current count of an
>   array. For example, if an array contains two objects, its size is 2,
>   so you can add objects at indices 0, 1, or 2. Index 3 is illegal and
>   out of bounds; if you try to add an object at index 3 (when the size
>   of the array is 2), NSMutableArray raises an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the NSMutableArray, UserValuesObject is nil and therefore is not allowing you to set any objects of the array.

Try checking to see if the array is nil or not before you enter the for loop.

i.e

```
if (UserValuesObject == nil) {
    UserValuesObject = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```